# Running pitest using ant java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion

Tags: java, pitest

I am getting below error when executing pi test

```
runFFMutation:
11:15:05 AM PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem, please enable it before reporting an issue.
11:15:06 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : Error: Could not find or load main class org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion
11:15:06 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion
```

Comment: Add information on how you run pitest and how your project looks

Comment: I have used https://github.com/hcoles/pitest-ant-example ..as it is ..and landed with same error

Comment: @SandeepPandey if the ant example is failing then there is some sort of enviromental issue with your machine. If you enable verbose logging (verbose="true" in the task) and update your question with the output it may be possible to help.

Comment: hi @henry thanks for response..what is expected java and ant version for this project?

Comment: It's an old example, so is limited to Java 8 unless you upgrade the pitest libs. Just tried it and it runs fine with ant 1.10.8. It will have been originally tested against whatever the current release was in 2014.

Comment: for me it worked when i reordered path env variable